# Size and contains methods of List in Drools

Tags: drools

Is it possible write conditions on the basis of size of a list using guided editors (either guided decision table or guided rule) and to check if any element is present in the list?

For eg.

```
User { 
    List of badges;
}
```

now I want to apply condition on number of badges and if a specific badge is in user's list of badges.

Also can I compare to objects. For eg. condition on count of badges of two users?

I'm using KIE Drools Workbench

Here's how source code should look like :-

```
import com.demo.dto.User;
import com.demo.dto.Badges;

rule  "Compare two variables"

when 
$badge : Badges() 
$user : User(name == "Sam", badges.size() >= 9, $badge memberOf badges)

then
$user.setService($user.getService() + $user.getBadges().size());

end
```

Comment: Is the question whether creating such a rule is generally possible, or whether it's possible with some graphical tool? In case of the latter, you could provide an example of how the rule should look in source code instead of just the list it should operate on.

Comment: Updated the question to include source code how generated source should look like.

Comment: ...but the DRL source is not correct. `memberOf` cannot be used as an operator between a Pattern and an expression. If you want to express that a user should have at least one badge, say so in the context of the User pattern: `User(..., badges.size() > 0)`. -- And calling `$user.getImpact()` requires parentheses.

Comment: Thanks Laune I updated the source code, I want to check if it's possible to map these decision tables like can I have $badge memberOf badges as condition with true or false as optional values?